# Day time over dates graph

Tags: python, tableau-api

I need to create a chart like this:

[image]

**X Axis:** Dates. I can present it either as a categorical (and order it somehow, even by another field) axis or as a continues axis.

**Y Axis:** Date Time (from 00:00 to 23:59)

The bars represent occurrences of events.

Emphasis points:

1. I might have some parallel occurrence (as you can see in the last date which is visualized in the graph). I can separate them with a field.
2. Event might start at any time and any day and continue to the next day (as you can see in the second and the third days above). I want them to be visualized as in the above chart. (solutions that based on separating them to 2 different events are not relevant here because of the final target - clustering).

Data can be arranged in any order either in Python or Tableau.